# How to fix JNI crash on env->NewObject?

Tags: java, c++, c, java-native-interface, clang

I'm trying to use Clang via JNI (Clang C-API).
One moment after few iteractions it just stop creating new objects and crashes:

> map method
>    0 args:
>   create Method instance 0x7fa26ba23c90 0x7fa26ba2a0c0 libclang: crash
>   detected during indexing source file: {   'source_filename' :
>   '/Users/asmirnov/Documents/dev/src/clang_jni/mac/test/TestFile.h'
>   'command_line_args' : ['-c', '-x', 'c++'],   'unsaved_files' : [],
>   'options' : 0, }

The code is pretty straight-forward:

```
mapMethod(JNIEnv *env, const CXIdxDeclInfo *info) {

    debug("map method");

    int numArgs = clang_Cursor_getNumArguments(info->cursor);
    debug("  %i args:", numArgs);

    debug("create Method instance %p %p", MethodClass, MethodConstructor);
    jobject result = env->NewObject(MethodClass, MethodConstructor);

    debug("create Method  params instance");
```

Method class and constructor is found and registered as globals correctly (seems to be) and it works few iterations:

```
// method
    MethodClass = (jclass)env->NewGlobalRef(env->FindClass("name/antonsmirnov/clang/dto/index/Method"));
    debug(MethodClass != NULL ? "found MethodClass" : "not found MethodClass");

    MethodConstructor = env->GetMethodID(MethodClass, "<init>", "()V");
    debug(MethodConstructor != NULL ? "found MethodConstructor" : "not found MethodConstructor");
```

I've read some "jni tips and tricks" articles and tried to `env->DeleteLocalRef` and make local references count too big just to try, but no result:

```
// magic 
    jint ensureResult = env->EnsureLocalCapacity(1024);
    debug("ensure result %i", ensureResult);

    jint pushResult = env->PushLocalFrame(1024);
    debug("push result %i", pushResult);
```

Clang is hijacking exception so i can't see the real reason.
The problem happens after few iterations as i said so it seems to be some limit exceeded problem or smth.

What is wrong?

**UPDATE**: I've done some research and i found that if i delete some local vars before then i can get one iteration more and one object instance more. So it makes me feel that it's using 16 local vars indeed and ignore my `EnsureLocalCapacity` invocation. Where should it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed using `EnsureLocalCapacity` in `JNI_OnLoad()` (did not work in each native method call).

Comment: Hard to believe that worked. It should only affect the JNI method currently being called.

Comment: Anyway it works. MBA-Anton:build asmirnov$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_51-b11-457)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.51-b01-457, mixed mode), mac os mavericks

Answer (score 1):

objects created via NewObject, FindClass，needed to be freed via DeleteLocalRef(), since number of local variables are limited in jni. or you can use `EnsureLocalCapacity` in `JNI_OnLoad()`.